# BankID app says something went wrong while authenticating with `https://client-test.grandid.com`

Tags: bankid

I have an authentication flow setup with grandid apis. I am from india, and to use BankID i've setup bankid with one of the demo bankid accounts retrieved from `https://demo.bankid.com/login`.

Following the docs of grandid I found they have a test environment `https://client-test.grandid.com` and I am assuming that my demo bankid should work there (because it's a test environment) but it seems like it does not. Everytime I authenticate it says `Something went wrong`.

Do I need a real bankID in order for grandid to work ?

BankID app Version: 7.33.21.3 CUST.